# Fade Out CSS Jquery OnClick Event

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

I am trying to fade out the current div by changing the css properties on the `onclick` event. The div is hidden successfully but the animation doesn't work. Any ideas as to why?

```
<div style="position:relative;" onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');thevid.style.display='block';this.style.opacity='0';this.style.width='0';this.style.height='0';this.style.transition='opacity 1800ms, height 0 1800ms, width 0 1800ms';document.getElementById('iframe').src=document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');">
Click me to hide
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/truncated..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the transition first?  Before hiding it?

Comment: tried that now, doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a function and add an event. Try to avoid add inline script. It is not a good practice, a sample example below:

```js
var fade_speed = 50; //500 ms

function fadeOut() {
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("clickme");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 0.1) {
            fadeTarget.style.display = "none";
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        } else {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        }
    }, fade_speed);
}

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener('click', fadeOut);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme" style="position:relative;">
  Click me to hide
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/truncated..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<span>TEST, ignore me</span>
```

Option 2, jQuery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="clickme" style="position:relative;">
  Click me to hide
</div>
<div id="thevideo">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/truncated..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<span>TEST, ignore me</span>

<script>
  // A $( document ).ready() block.
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#thevideo').fadeOut(500);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: If possible, I would prefer to just have the code on the onclick event in this instance. If this is not possible due to limitations of Jquery, then I will use this function.

Comment: or perhaps using just a CSS solution ?

Comment: actually I tried this, and the animation works but the div is not set to display:none... this leaves a big white gap

Comment: also.. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.. on other pages

Comment: @JoannaMikalai check the updated code, added `fadeTarget.style.display = "none";` so it will remove the space too.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai I'm not using jQuery here, it is pure JS, are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes I am .. sorry for not mentioning

Comment: @JoannaMikalai it is much easier using jquery, check the 2nd example, if you want to use inline js, do it with the `<script>` tag, much cleaner code

Comment: Daniel, the jquery option doesn't work. Both the clickme and thevideo IDs are being fade out.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai 2nd one? It only hide the `thevideo`... reload your page, check it again maybe

Comment: @JoannaMikalai make sure your jquery loaded before you call a jquery function.